# Android SafeArgs Array not compatible

Tags: android

I'm currently exploring the [Android Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) including the use of SafeArgs and I'm having a problem to it.

I try to set an array argument on navigation.

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/firstFragment">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="args"
            app:argType="CustomModel[]" />
    </action>
</fragment>

<fragment android:id="@+id/secondFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="args"
        app:argType="CustomModel[]" />
</fragment>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private List<CustomModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

private void getData() {
    // Some API calls
    dataList.clear();
    dataList.addAll(result.data);
}

private void navigateToNextFragment() {
    navHostController.navigate(
            FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(dataList)
    );
}
```

and the error is `error: incompatible types: List<CustomModel> cannot be converted to CustomModel[]`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A list is not an array... Convert your list to an array: `dataList.toArray(new CustomModel[0])`

Answer (score 3):

you should define you models like this :

```
@Parcelize
data class CustomModel(var name: String, val age: Int): Parcelable

@Parcelize
class CustomModels: ArrayList<CustomModel>(), Parcelable
```

and define in navgraph :

```
 <argument
  android:name="customModels"
  app:argType="com.test.test.CustomModels"/>
```